# Create variables with years based on the start and end dates

Tags: sas

I need to create variables that will mark in what years the treatment was taken by the patient.
I have data set that looks like this (data includes treatment periods, so 1 patient can have multiple rows of different treatments):

ID/    atc_label /   sdate     / enddate

1 /  VitD  / 31Oct2005  / 24Jan2005

1 / Steroid / 31Oct2008  / 24Jan2015

2 / Steroid / 15Oct2005  / 21Dec2010

3 / systemic/ 15Oct2007  / 21Dec2017

...

What I need is to create variables 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009.. until 2018. that will hold the correct atc_label value if the treatment was used during this year.

I did start with the Year function, but I do not know how to create the intermediate variables between the start and end date.
I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Please post some more rows of data that illustrate how your data is formatted and show anything you've tried. You can use the YEAR() function for starters to find the start/end of the period. Do you know the amount of year variables and period you'll need ahead of time?

Comment: Hi Reeza.  I need it for 2005-2018. I only need to mark if treatment happened during the year.

Comment: You do need to show what you've tried (code) in the future, SO is not a code writing service. We're more than happy to help with questions that show an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is with an array, indexed with the years.

```
data want;
set have;

*declare array variables to hold flags;
array flags(2000:2018) flag2000-flag2018;

*set to missing to avoid carry over from previous line;
call missing(of flags(*));

*calculate start and end years based on dates;
year_start =year(sdate);
year_end = year(enddate);

*loop and set years to 1 between year start and end;
do year=year_start to year_end;
    flags(year) = 1;
end;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to make the code to work.

Here is my solution that does what I needed:

```
data want;
set have;

*calculate start and end years based on dates;
year_start =year(stdt);
year_end = year(enddt);

run;


data want;
set have;

*declare array variables to hold flags;
array flags(2010:2018)$ flag2010-flag2018;

*set to missing to avoid carry over from previous line;
call missing(of flags(*));

*loop and set years to 1 between year start and end;
 do year = year_start to year_end by 1;
 flags(year) = atc_label;
end;

run;
```